# Any Open Street Map SDK or library for Windows CE 6.0

Tags: openstreetmap, windows, sdk

I have been assigned a task to develop a navigation app for Windows CE 6.0 and I was going through Frameworks and there is only osmsharp that supports windows phones, are there any sdk or libraries specifically for Windows CE 6 development that fullfill the need of development of a navigation app at least having basic features along with offline?

Comment: This makes me curious to know who on earth still uses Windows CE 6? The most recent version is 11 years old, and extended supported ended 2 years ago.

Comment: [ArcPad](https://support.esri.com/en/products/apps/mobile-apps/arcpad) is an option you could look into. It runs on Windows Mobile 5 – 6.5, it has a scripting interface, and I believe it also has support for navigation / routing. And to my surprise, Esri even offers support until December 2021.

Comment: @Berend I know, you must feel my pain.Thanks for the suggestion, let me have a look